# Isomorphism as an R-module not algebraically

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that the $k$-algebras $k\times k$ and $k[x]/(x^2)$ are isomorphic as $R$-modules, but not as rings, with $k$ is a field.

Suppose for the contrary that $k\times k \cong k[x]/(x^2)$. Then there is $\phi : k \times k \rightarrow k[x]/(x^2)$ isomorphism, so $\phi(s)\phi(s^{-1})=1_{k[x]/(x^2)}$ which means $\phi(s)$ is a unit in $k[x]/(x^2)$. So $\phi(s)=m+(x^2)$ for some $0 \neq m \in k$ and it is a unit since generally we have $k$ is a field. I want to conclude somehow that $kerf$ is not trivial to get a contradiction but I am getting stuck with my assumption. Also, I want to ask about the construction of the isomorphism function for $R-$ module.

I appreciate any help or hints.

Comment: You mean as $k$-modules ($k$-vector spaces), not as $R$-modules. There is no $R$ anywhere. Think about the multiplicative structure in $k \times k$ and in $k[x]/(x^2)$. Do you know what nilpotent elements are?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for the $k$-module part, you can convince yourself that $k[x]/(x^2) = \{\alpha + \beta x + (x^2) \mid \alpha,\beta \in k\}$, and then the map $k \times k \to k[x]/(x^2)$ given by $(\alpha,\beta) \mapsto \alpha + \beta x + (x^2)$ will work.

As for not being isomorphic as rings, suppose that they are, say $\phi: k \times k \to k[x]/(x^2)$ is an isomorphism. Notice that in $k \times k$, any non-zero element does not square to zero. Indeed, if $(a,b)^2 = (a^2,b^2) = 0$, then $a = b = 0$. With this in mind, let $y \in k \times k$ be such that $\phi(y) = x + (x^2)$ in $k[x]/(x^2)$ (surjectivity). But then $x^2 + (x^2) = (x^2)$ implies that $(x^2) = \phi(y^2) = \phi(y)^2$, which implies that $y^2 = 0$ (injectivity). But as we just mentioned, this would imply that $y = 0$ which clearly is a clear contradiction as $x + (x^2)$ is not zero.

As mentioned in the comments, this boils down to the quotient ring having nilpotents, while the product ring does not.

Comment: Is true in general that field must not have a nilpotent?

Comment: I can see that since field is an integral domain..

Comment: @Ahmed keep in mind that $k \times k$ is not a field, nor an integral domain ($(1,0)(0,1) = (0,0)$). But yes, in general integral domains won't have niltpotents since (non-zero) nilpotents are necessarily zero divisors.